# Meaning of 鑑定士 in English or French

Tags: translation

The 鑑定士【かんていし】 I have in mind is the one that this an expert about a type of goods (e.g. brand bags, diamonds, luxury watches), and is able to recognize and value them. He often use his knowledge in pawn shops or in auctions of such goods.

The term "expert" is too vague. The term "appraiser" seems very close but a bit old-fashioned to me, but I am not native in English so I may be wrong.

Which verb would you associate with this work (鑑定【かんてい】する)?

I know this is not a translation service, but I believe the term is technical enough to deserve a question.

Comment: I think the verb `appraise` is fairly common in English, but maybe it's just me but the noun `appraiser` does seem to be used a lot less.

Comment: Maybe 'Evaluator'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think appraiser (US English) is the word that you are looking for. **Valuer** (British English) and **valuator** (archaic British English) seem to be synonyms.

Valuer:

1. A valuer is someone whose job is to estimate the cost or value of something, for example a house, or objects that are going to be sold in an auction. [(Source)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/valuer)
2. A person whose job is to estimate the value of something that is to be purchased. [(Source)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/valuer)

Valuator:

1. a person who estimates the value of objects, paintings, etc; appraiser  [(Source)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/valuator)
2. one that valuates, specifically one that appraises [(Source)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valuator)

Answer (score 3):

specialist/specialize
connoisseur/appraise or judge or evaluate
an authority on X/ same verbs as above

Answer (score 0):

Take "不動産鑑定士" as example, there is a English term "Real estate Appraiser" used for someone who determines the fair market value of things.